# What's a good URL shortening script?

Tags: php, url-shortener

What's a good URL shortening script that does the following things?

- It is customizable (HTML and CSS)
- Users can create accounts
- Users can delete shortened URLs
- There is a bookmarklet
- Users can set privacy codes
- Some sort of API (so Twitter clients could use it, etc.)

Thanks a `document.write(Math.random()*Math.pow(10,18));`
:)

Comment: Are you looking for a script of sorts to implement this, or simply looking for an existing service such as tinyurl.com and such?

Comment: I think he wants the code behind such services.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't used any of these, but a quick googling turns up lots of results

Here's a good [tutorial](http://snook.ca/archives/php/url-shortener) on how to do it yourself

Here's a php [implementation](http://briancray.com/2009/08/26/free-php-url-shortener-script/) you can use for free

The user account creation side of things is a separate issue and I'm not aware of any url-shortening scripts that would consider that. You might want to look into using [openID](http://openid.net/) providers for your authentication, though.

Answer (score 1):

HotScripts looks like it has [a few](http://www.hotscripts.com/category/php/scripts-programs/redirection/url-based/).  Haven't used any but that might be a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [ur.ly](http://ur.ly/).  I use it almost daily to compress URL's.

If you want to use an API to interact with a URL compression service, [they have that](http://wiki.github.com/ajstiles/urly).  They also [publish their code](http://github.com/ajstiles/urly), so you can check it out if you want to do something similar.  It's written in Python.

ur.ly doesn't have accounts or allow deletion, but the code should help you get started.

**EDIT** for managing URL's using an account, you could try [bit.ly](http://bit.ly/), but they don't offer their code AFAICT.  They do offer an [API](http://bit.ly/apidocs), though, that includes authentication.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer Shrinky the free URL shortener, it’s free and it must be listed too :
[Shrinky - Free URL Shortener Script](http://cr.ma/shortener)

Comment: Welcome to SO. 
Link-only answers are not as helpful as answers that have working code plus helpful explanations. 
In this case, it would be worthwhile explaining this answer to a 5 year old.